# PyQt5 QTableView: how to disable user interaction/selection while keeping the default style/colors?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to be able to programmatically select some rows of a TableView, hence showing the selected rows to the user.
Of course the user should not be able to change the selected rows by clicking here and there.

Currently, the only way I found to disable the user's interaction is with:

```
self.table_view.setEnabled(False)
```

Altough this resolves the user's selection problem, it also changes the aspect of the table, making it all greyed out:

[image]

How can I restore the original style, with the selected rows displaying as blue?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open up QDesigner and load your .ui file. Click on your QTableView and in the Property Editor (right side panel) scroll down to the purple area. There you will see `editTriggers`, expand that. Check the first one that says `NoEditTriggers`.

This will disable the user from editing cells in the table. Let me know if my instructions weren't clear enough and I can provide pics.

Comment: I'm coding this all from scratch, not with QDesigner

Comment: Then try `self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)`.

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe 'cause it's not about editing, but selection.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you have to play with properties :

- setSelectionMode()
- setSelectionBehavior()

  ```
  table_view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
  table_view.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
  ```